# Validating the excel date for MM/dd/yyyy format

Tags: java, excel, apache, validation, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read Excel file(.xlsx) and validate its contents. 
We are having a date field in excel whcih should be in format MM/dd/yyyy.

Suppose if the date fild has two values as follows,

1) 04/24/2014 
2) 04242014

I have to accept the first one and reject the second. 
Since excel stores both these values in integer format, I am not able to differentiate them. 
Please suggest if you have any idea about how to solve this.

Comment: split date string using rgex.

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI allows to check data format of the cell with:

```
System.out.println(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell));
System.out.println(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString());
```

which gives for your first cell:

```
true
DD\/MM\/YYYY
```

and for second:

```
true
DDMMYYYY
```

Comment: Unfortunately this dint helped me. This is what i got for the dates which i entered.

Date:3/28/2014[
true
m/d/yy]

Date: 3282014 [
true
m/d/yy]

Comment: And what is your goal? Get the cell format or get the date from cell?

Comment: i have to validate the date. date should be in MM/dd/yyyy format. Either I can do it using SimpleDateFormat if i can get the excact contents(displayed values) of cell or i have to go with format(if there is such an option).  My ultimate aim is to make sure that the date is in MM/dd/yyyy format.